# Unable to connet to Oracle Server in Azure - ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor

Tags: oracle, azure

I have installed Oracle Server in Azure and I have tested my connection from a VM to the Oracle Server on both Public and Private IP Address on Port 1521 and it is successful, see image.

[image]

I have opened the firewall ports using the following configuration:

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=1521/tcp --permanent
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=5502/tcp --permanent
firewall-cmd --reload
```

I have started the listener and I got the following output

[image]

However, when I attempt to connect to the Oracle Server from my application I get the error

ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor

I have read multiple posts on SE about this issue and I think I have applied all of the suggestions, however I'm still not able to connect.

I have completed disabled the Firewall  on the VM that is attempting to connect to the Oracle Server.

The Oracle Server is installed on Linux

I'm not sure how to disable the firewall on Linux

Can someone let me know where I might be going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is coming *from the listener*.  Therefore, the request is getting to the listener, so it is not a routing or firewall issue.  Look at the error: "TNS listener does not currently know of service requested".  And look at the output of 'lsnrctl status'. See where it says 'The listener supports no services'.  So if it supports no services, it cannot know of the service requested.  If the listener supports no services, it's usually because the database is not started, and so did not register itself with the listener.

Comment: Hi @EdStevens, thanks for reaching out. The following is the output of lsnrctl status ```STATUS of the LISTENER
Alias                     LISTENER
Start Date                28-AUG-2021 17:48:17
Uptime                    0 days 2 hr. 38 min. 3 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
Listening Endpoints Summary...  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=oracledbv2.j3bwrtzg3r1uvatqmrybzhexaa.ax.internal.cloudapp.net)(PORT=1521)))
The listener supports no services
The command completed successfully
[oracle@oracledbv2 ~]$```

Comment: Hi @EdStevens, this is a silly question but can you let me know how to determine if that database is actually running?